# Jekyll command runs in every new Terminal window

Tags: command-line, terminal, jekyll

When I open up a new Terminal window or tab **Jekyll automatically tries to build a site in the current directory**. For obvious reasons I have uninstalled the Jekyll gem so that this does not mess up any other projects that I am working on, but the command still attempts to run. I have not changed any of the preferences to run a custom command in new terminal windows. I can't find where the jekyll command is being triggered. A search for any files containing 'jekyll' including system and hidden files turns up negative. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your shell is bash try adding

```
set -x
```

near the top of ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile. That will echo everything your shell does to stdout, which may help you track down the problem.

Comment: There was a commented-out alias in my bash_profile that was triggering it. Removing that and sourcing my bash_profile fixed it. Thanks!